# How to find the highest value of something based on the maximum value of other attribute?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with one column corresponding to the position's ID and the other columns corresponding to their funding rate and funding percentage.

[image]

As you can see, there're multiple columns in this excel sheet. Let me explain what I need from this sheet. First, there are positions which some of them are duplicated, such as position# 30003831, 30003840, etc. So I created a column with a unique position ID(duplicate values are removed). So I want to write a formula to find the highest "Fund" of each position based on its highest "%split". For instance:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI: I use python as well. If there's a code that can solve this problem, that would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Use `MAXIFS` or `MAX(IF())` if your version of Excel doesn't support `MAXIFS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Pivot Table:

[image]

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)
>
> [Excel Pivot Table Filters - Top
> 10](https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-filters-top10.html)

I did this when creating my Pivot Table:

1. Field `position id` to rows section
2. Field `% split` to rows section **and also** to values section
3. Field `fund` to values section
4. Applied filter to field `% split` in rows section. My filter is just TOP 1

[image]

[image]